# How do I enable the built-in wireless on my hp mini 110-3710?

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek

How do I enable the built-in wireless on my hp mini 110-3710?

There is no check mark next to Enable wireless. It disable wireless when you try it.

My wirelss card is greyed out (RTL8188CE) and says wireless is disabled under it.

If I plug in a USB wifi adapter it works without a problem. Definitly an issue with internal wifi card. The wifi button on the keyboard will disable all wireless if I press it. It will grey out the ENABLE WIRELESs on the network manager if pressed, and will ungrey it when pressed again. So it seems to have no effect on the actual hardware. Just on the wireless networking service.

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:df:9a:93:82:be
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:55000000-55003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 44:1e:a1:cd:cc:d3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:52004000-52004fff memory:52000000-52003fff


0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: sudo lshw -class network:PCI (sysfs)

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: ok, I will run them again with the usb device removed. If I don´t connect it. I have no way of getting the results to you.

Comment: ok added to question

Comment: sudo rmmod -f acer-wmi gave an error. NO SUCH FILE

Comment: just tried "sudo rfkill unblock all" and reran the previous commands. The results were static. I did want to post the same thing twice.

Comment: try `modprobe -r acer-wmi` before `sudo rfkill unblock all` - any changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line:

```
sudo modprobe hp-wmi
sudo service network manager restart
```

Comment: that did do anything except disable my usb wireless device again.

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: OK, just  did the sudo modprobe hp-wmi and restarted the network-manager daemon. Now I lost all wifi even the USB now greyed out and says "wireless is disabled by hardware switch."

Comment: Hmm... Does it say anywhere on your computer what wireless network adapter it uses?

Comment: It shows up as an RTL8188CE using driver=rtl8192ce v3.0.0-12 which is the latest. I'm stating to think I should compile and install hp-wmi from source. Maybe there is an update that fixes this bug.

Comment: That's strange, it should be working. Before you recompile the driver from source, file a bug report on launchpad.

Comment: Wish it were that easy.. They make it impossible. They tell you to type ubuntu-bug in the command line, then pick a category, when you pick "other" they tell you that you need a package name. When you enter "ubuntu-bug hp-wmi" they tell you it doesn't exit. I don't know.. I give up.